# Can't seem to fix this issue of multiple Python Instances conflicting via PIP. How can I side step around this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, installation

My `MacBook Pro High Sierra` has `Python 2.7` installed as well as `Python 3.7` both of which were downloaded from their binaries off the general Python website.

I'm trying to install an R console `rtichoke`; so like every time, I use:

```
pip install -U rtichoke
```

The response I get is consistent `requirements already met`. So it's installed. But in terminal upon typing the command `rtichoke` to get it to run I get:

```
bash: rtichoke: command not found
```

Essentially my installs via `PIP/Python` are unable to be used from the general terminal. This seems like an issue with my .bash_profile and PATH. But I'm not well versed with that to even attempt at a fix. Here is a copy of my current .bash including the automatically set PATHs from the Python binaries.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Brew
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"



test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"

#Alias
alias r="rtichoke"
```

I've gotten a few suggestions to do this in a virtual environment but I can't say I know too much about that either. Ideally I'd like to go fixing any inconsistent installs but nevertheless ANY HELP IS SO APPRECIATED. I've spent hours with this and CANNOT figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked if `rtichoke` is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` or `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` ? I am guessing it is in another folder which you need to identify first

Comment: Try using python2.7 -m pip install -U rtichoke

Alternatively use pip -V to see whether its pointing to python 2.7 or 3

Comment: you can also use pip2 and pip3 to install to the respective versions (check the names of the pip executables in both distributions to make sure)

Comment: @FlyingTeller - it's in neither of those folders. I can't actually seem to find any executable. Ordinarily on other computer installs it's in '/usr/local/bin/'. Though when I run 'python' then 'help("modules"): I get rtichoke listed there.

Comment: @SagarDawda running pip -V returns `pip 18.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

Comment: If it's of note, when I run `pip list` I DO in fact see rtichoke listed. rtichoke just doesn't execute upon calling: which is why I thought it was an issue with my ~/.profile.

Comment: @FlyingTeller alright so I found the directory. Using `pip show -f rtichoke` it returns  ```~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages```. 
Then a series of files: ```../../../bin/rtichoke  
rtichoke-0.2.1.dist-info/INSTALLER```

Comment: Can you access `/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/../../../bin/rtichoke` Is tht were the executable is?

Comment: I suggest you download Anaconda with Python 3.6 and use that distribution. Anaconda makes it very simple to create and manage virtual environments. I've been using it for years and it works great. I  am in no way affiliated with Anaconda, just a satisfied user.  I read all these questions of people struggling with python and I want to send them all a link to Anaconda. https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

Comment: I agree with @jmh 

Anaconda will make your life simple

Comment: @SagarDawda and just leave my Python instance as is? I've searched all over the place for a solution to this; it really seems to be a problem. I'll probably switch over to conda as suggested at this point. But still want to fix these mangled install directories

Comment: Alright I think I fixed it. I added my user base's binary directory to my path. I ran `python -m site --user-base` to get the directory, then just added /bin/ to that. Added it to bash and I've been able to execute rtichoke straight from terminal.